# Why isn't the Dfun(gradient) called while using integrate.odeint in SciPy?

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

Can anyone provide an example of providing a Jacobian to a `integrate.odeint` function in SciPy?.
I try to run this code from SciPy tutorial [odeint example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#ordinary-differential-equations-odeint) but seems that `Dfun()` (the Jacobian function) is never called.

```
from numpy import * # added
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.special import gamma, airy
y1_0 = 1.0/3**(2.0/3.0)/gamma(2.0/3.0)
y0_0 = -1.0/3**(1.0/3.0)/gamma(1.0/3.0)
y0 = [y0_0, y1_0]


def func(y, t):
    return [t*y[1],y[0]]
    
    
def gradient(y,t):
    print 'jacobian'  # added
    return [[0,t],[1,0]]
    
    
x = arange(0,4.0, 0.01)
t = x
ychk = airy(x)[0]
y = odeint(func, y0, t)
y2 = odeint(func, y0, t, Dfun=gradient)
print y2 # added
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Under the hood, [`scipy.integrate.odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html#scipy.integrate.odeint) uses the LSODA solver from the [ODEPACK FORTRAN library](http://www.netlib.org/odepack/opks-sum). In order to deal with situations where the function you are trying to integrate is [stiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiffness_%28mathematics%29), LSODA switches adaptively between two different methods for computing the integral - [Adams' method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdamsMethod.html), which is faster but unsuitable for stiff systems, and [BDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_differentiation_formula), which is slower but robust to stiffness.

The particular function you're trying to integrate is non-stiff, so LSODA will use Adams on every iteration. You can check this by returning the `infodict` (`...,full_output=True`) and checking `infodict['mused']`.

Since Adams' method does not use the Jacobian, your gradient function never gets called. However if you give `odeint` a stiff function to integrate, such as the [Van der Pol equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_equation):

```
def vanderpol(y, t, mu=1000.):
    return [y[1], mu*(1. - y[0]**2)*y[1] - y[0]]

def vanderpol_jac(y, t, mu=1000.):
    return [[0, 1], [-2*y[0]*y[1]*mu - 1, mu*(1 - y[0]**2)]]

y0 = [2, 0]
t = arange(0, 5000, 1)
y,info = odeint(vanderpol, y0, t, Dfun=vanderpol_jac, full_output=True)

print info['mused'] # method used (1=adams, 2=bdf)
print info['nje']   # cumulative number of jacobian evaluations
plot(t, y[:,0])
```

you should see that `odeint` switches to using BDF, and the Jacobian function now gets called.

If you want more control over the solver, you should look into [`scipy.integrate.ode`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html), which is a much more flexible object-oriented interface to multiple different integrators.

Comment: Perfect. More clear than SciPy documentation. This is exactly what I want, thanks ali_m!